# Print how many times a sequence of characters appears in a string

Tags: beginner, c

Given a string, count how many times a sequence of characters (in this code, the sequence is "ei") appears until the user types '#', then print the amount. I would like to know how to improve the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch, cur_ch, last_ch;
    cur_ch = '\0';
    uint16_t count = 0;

    puts("Enter a string (# to finish):");
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '#')
    {
        last_ch = cur_ch;
        cur_ch = ch;

        if (last_ch == 'e' && cur_ch == 'i')
            count++;
    }

    printf("There %s %" PRIu16 " %s.\n", count == 1 ? "is" : "are", count,
    count == 1 ? "ei" : "ei's");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Missed detection of `EOF`: `getchar()` returns an `int` with values in the range of `unsigned char` and the negative value of `EOF`.  Saving that result in a `char` loses distinctiveness should `getchar()` return `EOF` due to `stdin` becoming closed or input error.

   ```
   //char ch;
   //while ((ch = getchar()) != '#')
   int ch;
   while ((ch = getchar()) != '#' && ch != EOF)
   ```
2. Why `uint16_t`?  The input stream can be excessively long, and certainly more than 65,535.  Suggest a wider type.  (Good that code uses an unsigned integer.)

   ```
   // uint16_t count = 0;
   unsigned long long  = 0;
   ```
3. Code could do this with 2 variables rather than 3.

   ```
   int ch;
   previous = EOF;

   while ((ch = getchar()) != '#' && ch != EOF) {
     if (previous == `e` && ch == `i') {
       count++;
     }
     previous = ch;
   }
   ```
4. Recommend `{}`

   ```
   // if (last_ch == 'e' && cur_ch == 'i')
   //     count++;
   if (last_ch == 'e' && cur_ch == 'i') {
       count++;
   }
   ```
5. Grammar: Code goes though work to print `are` vs. `is` yet does not make correct with `ei's` vs. `ei`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Easier customization

In this code the sequence (`ei`) is specified inside the logic (the `if` statement. I suggest declaring the first and last char as constants at the top of your code to make changes and experimentation easier.

Another good solution is writing a function to check if two chars are consecutively present in the user input and supplyng `ei` as an argument in `main`.

Comment: Good point about the "constants at the top of your code".